# htacces redirection

Tags: url, redirect

I would like to remove the filename from a "subdirectory" URL and just display the subdirectory in the browser URL.

So:
    www.domain.com.au/login/public_index.php

becomes:

```
www.domain.com.au/login/
```

I have tried various solutions from this site and the internet, but none have worked.

If possible I would like to put the new redirection in the root htaccess file?? and not in the subdirectory htaccess file?

*** Just in case other redirections in the htaccess file are in conflict with any new subdirectory redirections, here are the other (and necessary) redirections in the htaccess file that perform important jobs:

```
#(1) A redirection to remove root level index.php from the url
# Redirect index.php to domain.com.au
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.domain.com.au/ [R=301,L]

#(2) 
# Redirect   domain.com.au    to    www.domain.com,au
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com.au [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]

#(3)
# Force SSL on login directory
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} login 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com.au/$1 [R,L]
```

Any help would be appreciated as all solutions to add the new subdirectory URL redirect thus far have failed.

Regards,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to what you did in `#(1)`:

```
#(4)
# remove public_index.php 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+)/public_index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule public_index\.php$ http://www.domain.com.au/%1/ [R=301,L]

# internally add it back
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/public_index.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1/public_index.php [L]
```

That's for any subdirectory, but if you're only interested in `login`, that gets easier:

```
#(4)
# remove public_index.php 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /login/public_index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule public_index\.php$ https://www.domain.com.au/login/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?login/?$ /login/public_index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! Amazing, saved me hours from having to learn "another" language in depth.